Why am I receiving slot change updates in batches?
I'm listening to slot changes and I noticed I'm receiving the updates in batches, meaning I receive a bunch of them almost at the same time, then wait 1-2 seconds and I receive another bunch. Instead, I was expecting to receive one every 400ms.
I'm using with the following code:
const connection = new Connection(
  RPC_URL,
  {
    wsEndpoint: RPC_URL_WS,
    commitment: "confirmed",
  }
)    
connection.onSlotChange(async (slotInto) => {
  console.log(`${getCurrentDateTimeUTC()} ${slotInto.slot}`)
})

this prints something like this (I added the spaces to highlight the 'batches':
2024-07-22T01:20:32.731Z 278921873
2024-07-22T01:20:32.732Z 278921874
2024-07-22T01:20:32.732Z 278921875
2024-07-22T01:20:32.732Z 278921876

2024-07-22T01:20:34.680Z 278921877
2024-07-22T01:20:34.680Z 278921878
2024-07-22T01:20:34.680Z 278921879
2024-07-22T01:20:34.681Z 278921880
2024-07-22T01:20:34.681Z 278921881

2024-07-22T01:20:36.110Z 278921882
2024-07-22T01:20:36.111Z 278921883
2024-07-22T01:20:36.111Z 278921884

2024-07-22T01:20:37.211Z 278921885
2024-07-22T01:20:37.211Z 278921886

2024-07-22T01:20:38.436Z 278921887
2024-07-22T01:20:38.437Z 278921888
2024-07-22T01:20:38.437Z 278921889
2024-07-22T01:20:38.442Z 278921890

Is this expected? I thought slots should be every 400ms. Am I missing something?
